# iphone use of the function

Tags: iphone

can anyone tell me the function of following code. is the code line

```
NSString* fileName = @"text.txt";
```

used for reading the file from a location in the system?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];    
    NSString* fileName = @"text.txt";
    NSString *fileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: fileName];  
    NSArray *lines = [fileString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];      
   [pool drain];  
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes it does, however it's not obvious where it'll look for it. I think in the simulator it'll try to read it from / of your harddisk. On a device I think it tries to read it from the root of the application sandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fileName is a string that has will return you the following output

```
text.txt
```

This is because you have assigned that value to it read your code once more.

If you want to store the reference of some file that is inside your bundle then in that case i would suggest using the NSBundle class refer to Rams answer and get the job done buddy

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"text" ofType:@"txt"];